# Makefile with Docker Compose, how to prevent from build every time?

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose

I've a `Makefile` for a Docker Compose stack:

```
.PHONY: build

docker-compose.yml:
    cp docker-compose.yml.dist docker-compose.yml

build: docker-compose.yml
    docker-compose -p xxx build
```

But every time I launch `make build` the `docker-compose -p xxx build` command is executed. Is it possible to run the build only when needed? I'd like to know the bests practices about that, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is a direct consequence of having declared the `build` target as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets).

In the specific case of `docker build` and wrappers around it, it should run very quickly if nothing in the image has changed.  (It's a little bit more expensive than re-running `make`; it will only be slow if the directory tree is very large.)  One way to go here is to just ignore it and always rebuild things.

Another common pattern you'll see in Makefiles is to use artificial files to track whether specific steps in the build pipeline sequence have happened.  You need to be very good about declaring *all* of your dependencies for this to work well.

```
.PHONY: build clean

build: .build.docker

.build.docker: docker-compose.yml Dockerfile app
        docker-compose -f $< build
        touch $@

docker-compose.yml: docker-compose.yml.dist
        cp $< $@

app: $(SOURCES:%=%.o)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(SOURCES:%=%.o) $(LIBS)

clean:
        rm -f .build.docker docker-compose.yml app
```

Say you change your `docker-compose.yml.dist` file.  With this Makefile, it will trigger the rule to `cp` it to `docker-compose.yml`, then the rule to rebuild the image, and then it will update the timestamp on the `.build.docker` file.  Similarly, if you update any of the source files making up your application, it will eventually need to cause the Docker image to be rebuilt.

But, say you haven't changed any of these things.  `build` is phony so it is always considered out-of-date, but it has no rules itself.  It checks the timestamp of the `.build.docker` file.  Since that's newer than `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile`, and `app` there is nothing to do and the image build gets skipped.